# Windows toolbar extension to show network usage?

Tags: windows, data-visualization, networking, graphs

I currently use [Softperfect's Networx](https://www.softperfect.com/products/networx/) which adds a little graphical display to the windows start bar at the bottom. The issue I have is that the software does a lot of other stuff that I don't need and has transitioned to a paid model so the version I use is out of date.

Is there some software which just adds a network usage graph that is lightweight (and preferably free) which integrates directly with the windows task bar (via a Toolbar)?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a lot more searching and detective work I found out that the little toolbar integrations are actually called `Deskband`s which is what they are referred to in the Windows documentation.

So with that knowledge it turns out that there are quite a few applications that will monitor network usage and show it in the toolbar.

### NetworkSummaryToolbar - [Link](https://github.com/crener/NetworkSummaryToolbar)

[image: NetworkSummaryToolbar]

This is what I ended up using, works quite well. Multiple graph rendering modes but I wish you could tweak the colours.

### Other options (that might interest you but didn't work for me)

[**NetView**](https://github.com/AzureGreen/NetView) - works but no graph

[image: NetView]

---

[**taskbar-monitor**](https://github.com/leandrosa81/taskbar-monitor) - works but style of graph doesn't match but does monitor CPU, Memory and Disk if your into that

[image: taskbar-monitor]

---

[**Perfmonbar**](https://xhmikosr.github.io/perfmonbar/) - allows monitoring crazy amounts of PC stats but all text based

[image: Perfmonbar]

---

[**MonBand**](https://github.com/rwasef1830/MonBand)

MonBand - might be good but no screenshot so no idea what it looks like :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use this software called [NetSpeedMonitor](https://download.cnet.com/NetSpeedMonitor-64-bit/3000-2085_4-77542868.html), it is used to monitor the current speed (up and downstream) of your Network Interfaces and the amount of data transferred.

Comment: Note that NetSpeedMonitor does not have a graph (like OP requested). It's still a great tool though.